# Setting TextView properties in a ListView - Strange Result

Tags: android

I have an activity with a ListView which is populated through a custom ArrayAdapter.  There is an array of objects which have a Boolean property called 'isRead'.  Based on the value of this property, I want to set the typeface of one of the TextViews in the row to either 'normal' or 'bold'.  I also set the color of the text to either 'gray' or 'black'

When the Activity initially starts up, everything works as expected.  If isRead is true, the text is gray with a normal font.  Once I scroll down the list and then scroll up again, the text of an object where isRead is true is colored gray, but the font is bold.

Am I doing something wrong here?  Or is this some Android strangeness?

ArrayAdapter code is below:

```
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
       LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
       View row = convertView;
       ArticleListRowViewWrapper wrapper=null;
       if (row == null) {
           row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.articlesrow, parent, false);
           wrapper = new ArticleListRowViewWrapper(row);
           row.setTag(wrapper);
       } else {
           wrapper = (ArticleListRowViewWrapper)row.getTag();
       }
       Article a = articles.get(position);
       String dateString = df.format(a.getPubDate());
       TextView titleLabel=wrapper.getTitleLabel();
       Typeface tf = titleLabel.getTypeface();
       if (a.getIsRead()) {
           titleLabel.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
           titleLabel.setTypeface(tf, Typeface.NORMAL);
       } else {
           titleLabel.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
           titleLabel.setTypeface(tf, Typeface.BOLD);
       }
       titleLabel.setText(a.getTitle());
       TextView dateLabel =wrapper.getDateLabel();
       dateLabel.setText(dateString);
       return row;
    }
}
```

Comment: where do you call setRead() ? can you also post this part of the code? it's important to mention that if you scroll, the view is draw again.

Comment: Adding to what Sebi said, I'd imagine it has something to do with the fact that view objects are reused as you scroll up and down.  However, I don't see any obvious problems with what you are doing...

Comment: The results I am getting prove that isRead is being set properly.  The text color is either GRAY or BLACK, depending on the state of the isRead property.  However, the typeface is NORMAL when the row is first drawn and BOLD if it is scrolled out of view and then back into view.  The text color remains consistent.

Comment: I agree that this probably has something to do with reuse.  But why is it only the typeface property that can't be set properly on a reused object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get this working with the following changed code snippet:

```
       Typeface tf = titleLabel.getTypeface();
       if (a.getIsRead()) {
           titleLabel.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
           titleLabel.setTypeface(Typeface.create(tf, Typeface.NORMAL));
       } else {
           titleLabel.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
           titleLabel.setTypeface(Typeface.create(tf, Typeface.BOLD));
       }
```

All credit to CommonsWare for help on this one.